# laravel 5.2 Insert login session data to database on custom auth

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom auth login in laravel 5.2, my config for custom login is

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'provider' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'providers',
        ],
    ],
```

I have two auth controllers, One is laravel AuthController and other is ProviderAuthController. I have set SESSION_DRIVER=database in my env and also created a session table in my database I am getting sessions from web login but problem is that I am not able to get sessions on provider login. Is there any workaround to insert session on provider login.

There is nothing in my app service provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function register()
 {
    //
 }
}
```

The route for my providerAuthcontroller are
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'provider'], function(){

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\ProviderAuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\ProviderAuthController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\ProviderAuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\ProviderAuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\ProviderAuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\ProviderPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ProviderPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ProviderPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why you use blockquotes and for all text. I had to edit it.

Comment: Did you register your new AuthController?
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: yes it is registered and working perfectly but it is not saving the user id in session table with which i am logging in

Comment: Can you share your AppServiceProvider code?

Comment: please check that there is nothing in my appserviceprovider

Comment: @GuanapadoPado are you able to supply your routes for your controllers, and what you've done differently in your `ProviderAuthController`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hassanshuja/2104c56004240fc05013670f269063af

Comment: above is the gist for my providerAuthController and also I have added my routes on my question, also note that now i am able to save the session of provider but it is not saving the user_id in session table

Comment: how are you registering your custom 'providers' provider?

Comment: I don't see `Auth\ProviderAuthController@login` in the gist you provided.  What is the reason you do not want to use the default auth controller?

Comment: This gist is for provider login controller https://gist.github.com/hassanshuja/e9176eb97acc9d7a7689a317ea8b8595

Comment: This gist is for AuthenticateProvider used in middleware https://gist.github.com/hassanshuja/f57bb036ca740a86ab4b39d8cdc3ffc0 This is for Redirection after authentication https://gist.github.com/hassanshuja/01bb700c30eaf0cb337f03014ac7a429

Answer (score 8):

Its supposed to happen in the middlewares, not in the providers.

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

and

```
class Auth
{
  public function handle(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, Closure $next)
  {
    if(!$request->session()->get('authenticated'){
      throw AuthException();
    }
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Also check [laravel lifecycle](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/52/understanding-the-request-lifecycle).

Comment: I am not asking about authenticating users , what I want is to get users session ids and ip of two types having two auth controller.

Comment: You shouldn't have two controllers in the same time. However you can add all the metadata that you need in middlewares. You can have eg. a SetupSessionidMiddleware, and a ValidateIpMiddleware.

Comment: @lintabá, How can i use middleware for my custom login form ? means what code i need to add in middleware function. You can find my question here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588304/laravel-i-need-to-create-one-login-form-where-customer-can-login-using-their-lo

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get session(just doing R&D that time). I think this  could work for you well.

```
    $req = $request->session()->all();
    $req = collect($req);
    $req = $req->filter(function($item,$key){
        return strripos($key,'web_');
    });
    $key =  $req->keys()->first();
    $session = explode('login_web_', $key)[1];
```